# Count the number of ones in an unsigned 16-bit integer

Tags: code-golf, binary, counting

Write some statement(s) which will count the number of ones in an unsigned sixteen-bit integer.

For example, if the input is `1337`, then the result is `6` because `1337` as a sixteen bit binary number is `0000010100111001`, which contains six ones.

Comment: Related but not dupe: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21326/sort-numbers-by-binary-1s-count) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47134/from-0-to-2n-1-in-popcorn-order)

Comment: [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4588/25180) [4](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4434/25180)

Comment: Tip: just as the some of digits in a number is congruent to the number mod 9, the some of bits equals the number mod 1.

Comment: @PyRulez Any number is zero modulo 1.

Comment: Hi, you have chosen a wrong answer as accepted answer (by default tie breaker logic of earliest post).

Comment: @Thomas I never said it was a helpful tip.

Comment: Why is this question attracting close votes AFTER most of the answers have been posted? Close voters please indicate your reason in the comments. If it is the acceptance of es1024's (very clever) 4-byte answer which does not comply with standard loopholes (because it uses a builtin) please state that this is the reason. Otherwise, what is it?

Comment: @Thomas Slight correction- any *integer* is zero modulo 1.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## 80386 Machine Code, 4 bytes

```
F3 0F B8 C1
```

which takes the integer in `cx` and outputs the count in `ax`, and is equivalent to:

```
popcnt ax, cx     ; F3 0F B8 C1
```

And here is an **<s>11</s> 10** byte solution not using POPCNT:

```
31 C0 D1 E9 10 E0 85 C9 75 F8
```

which is equivalent to:

```
xor ax, ax        ; 31 C0   Set ax to 0
shr cx, 1         ; D1 E9   Shift cx to the right by 1 (cx >> 1)
adc al, ah        ; 10 E0   al += (ah = 0) + (cf = rightmost bit before shifting)
test cx, cx       ; 85 C9   Check if cx == 0
jnz $-6           ; 75 F8   Jump up to shr cx, 1 if not
```

Comment: Is this in 32-bit or 16-bit (either real or protected) mode?

Comment: @FUZxxl The assembly provided is for 16-bit, though replacing `ax` and `cx` with `eax` and `ecx` changes it to 32-bit. The bytecode is the same for either.

Comment: @es1024 The byte code is the same _if_ this was compiled in 16-bit mode and the 32-bit version in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Isn't popcnt a builtin and thus falling foul of standard loopholes? Still credit for the second solution though.

Comment: When you claim the length *of the machine code*, shouldn't the title be "80386 Machine Code", not "80386 Assembler"?

Comment: Damn you beat me to POPCNT by a day!  Why don't I check this site more often...

Comment: At start of that what is the value for cx?

Comment: `85 C9 75 F8` => `41 E2 F9`?

Answer (score 15):

## Python 2, 17 bytes

```python
bin(s).count('1')
```

The `bin` built-in returns the integer converted to a binary string. We then count the `1` digits:

```python
>>> s=1337
>>> bin(s)
'0b10100111001'
>>> bin(s).count('1')
6
```

Answer (score 12):

### J (5 characters)

J has no explicit types. This does the right thing for all integers.

```
+/@#:
```

- `+/` the sum
- `@` of
- `#:` the base two representation

Answer (score 11):

## C,21

```
for(n=0;x;n++)x&=x-1;
```

you said "write some statements" (not "a function") so I've assumed the number is supplied in `x` and the number of 1's is returned in `n`. If I don't have to initialize `n` I can save 3 bytes.

This is an adaptation of the famous expression `x&x-1` for testing if something is a power of 2 (false if it is, true if it isn't.)

Here it is in action on the number 1337 from the question. Note that subtracting 1 flips the least significant 1 bit and all zeroes to the right.

```
0000010100111001 & 0000010100111000 = 0000010100111000
0000010100111000 & 0000010100110111 = 0000010100110000
0000010100110000 & 0000010100101111 = 0000010100100000
0000010100100000 & 0000010100011111 = 0000010100000000
0000010100000000 & 0000010011111111 = 0000010000000000
0000010000000000 & 0000001111111111 = 0000000000000000
```

EDIT: for completeness, here's the naive algorithm, which is one byte longer (and quite a bit slower.)

```
for(n=0;x;x/=2)n+=x&1;
```

Comment: Ref: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan

Comment: @edc65 so as it turns out, I reinvented the wheel. At least I saved 2 bytes by omitting the `{}`. It's such a simple task I shouldn´t be surprised someone already came up with it.

Comment: *"First published in 1960"*, impressive.

Comment: Correction to naive algorithm: `for(n=0;x;x/=2)n+=x&1;`

Comment: The naive implmentation `for(n=0;x;x/=2)n+=x&1;` gives a result which is different from, `for(n=0;x;n++)x&=x-1;` for `negative numbers`. Try with x=-7, the results are confusing !

Comment: @nmxprime the OP asks for unsigned int. for -7 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111001 on my 32 bit compiler, I get 30 for the fast algorithm, which is correct. For the naive algorithm, it iterates through -7, -7/2=-3, -3/2=-1, -1/2=0. That gives an incorrect answer. Changing x/=2 to x>>=1 may give the correct answer on some compilers, but C is undefined as to whether a 1 or a 0 is shifted into the empty bit for >> on negative numbers. Those compilers that shift a 1 in will go into an infinite loop. The workaround is to define x as an unsigned int. Then x=-7 loads (1<<32)-7=4294967289 into x.

Comment: Nice, 3 bytes shorter than n=__builtin_popcount(x);

Answer (score 8):

### [Jelly](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QlM&input=&args=MjM), 2 bytes

```
BS
```

Jelly is a new language written by @Dennis, with J-like syntax.

```
         implicit: function of command-line arguments
B        Binary digits as list
 S       Sum
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QlM&input=&args=MjM).

Comment: What is this BS‽ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
sjQ2
```

The program takes the number whose hamming weight is to be found on STDIN.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 19 bytes

```matlab
n->sum(digits(n,2))
```

This creates an anonymous function that accepts a single argument, `n`. To use it, assign it to something like `f=n->...` and call it like `f(1337)`.

The `digits()` function, when called with 2 arguments, returns an array of the digits of the input in the given base. So `digits(n, 2)` returns the binary digits of `n`. Take the sum of the array and you have the number of ones in the binary representation of `n`.

Comment: This can be a lot shorter: Julia has a function [`count_ones`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/numbers/?highlight=number#Base.count_ones)

Comment: @AndrewPiliser: Thanks for the suggestion, but built-in functions which exactly accomplish the task are considered a standard loophole and are frowned upon when not explicitly disallowed.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 24 bytes

```js
sum(intToBits(scan())>0)
```

`scan()` reads input from stdin.

`intToBits()` takes an integer and returns a vector of type `raw` containing the zeroes and ones of the binary representation of the input.

`intToBits(scan())>0` returns a logical vector where each element is `TRUE` if the corresponding binary vector element is a 1 (since all elements are 0 or 1 and 1 > 0), otherwise `FALSE`.

In R, you can sum a logical vector to get the number of `TRUE` elements, so summing the vector of logicals as above gets us what we want.

Note that `sum()` can't handle `raw` input directly, hence the workaround using logicals.

Comment: Wouldn't `sum(intToBits(scan()))` be the same?

Comment: @Sieg: Unfortunately no since `sum()` can't take input of type `raw`, which is what's returned from `intToBits()`.

Comment: That is really weird to me.

Comment: @Sieg: Yeah, it's weird to me too. Oh well. If every porkchop were perfect, we wouldn't have hotdogs.

Comment: And that's the weirdest metaphor ever.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 3 bytes

```apl
+/⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X1v/UdeS/2mP2iY86u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@mYMCVpmAIxEZAbAzEJiC@sbE5AA)

-5 from Adám.

```apl
  ⊤ convert to base 2
+/  sum
```

Comment: While this is as good as it gets in Vanilla, Extended has `+/⊤`

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```rust
u16::count_ones
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQ5qSUKaaV5yQq2/0sNzayskvNL80ri8/NSi/@DpK3BigqKMvNKcvIUNZSqa5V0wOo1DI2NzYE6NDWxKoHK6iGM0wCprP0PAA)

Rust is better than C because `count_ones` is shorter than `__builtin__popcount` :)

Every built-in integer type (unsigned or signed, 8/16/32/64/128 bits) supports this method. Since the challenge specifically asks for unsigned 16 bit integers, we use `u16` here. Also, while the method is usually called in the form of `some_number.count_ones()`, `u16::count_ones(some_number)` is also a valid syntax for calling the same function.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
b∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJi4oiRIiwiIiwiMTMzNyJd)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 1 byte

```
b
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiYiIsIiIsIjEzMzciXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
ri2b:+

ri         "Read the input and convert it to integer";
  2b       "Convert the integer into base 2 format";
    :+     "Sum the digits of base 2 form";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri2b%3A%2B&input=253)

Answer (score 3):

## [Joe](https://github.com/JaniM/Joe), 4 bytes

```
/+Ba
```

This is an anonymous function. `Ba` gives the binary representation of a number and `/+` sums it.

```
   (/+Ba)13
3
   (/+Ba)500
6
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> 18 bytes

*Thanks to alephalpha for reminding me of `DigitCount`.*

```
DigitCount[#,2,1]&
```

Comment: @alephalpha thanks, but DigitCount takes another parameter :)

Answer (score 3):

## ES6 (<del>34</del> <del>22</del> 21 bytes):

This is a simple recursive function that can be shortened a bit more.
It simply takes a bit and runs itself again:

```
B=n=>n&&(1&n)+B(n>>1)
```

Try it on http://www.es6fiddle.net/imt5ilve/ (you need the `var` because of `'use strict';`).

I can't believe I've beaten Fish!!!

The old one:

```
n=>n.toString(2).split(1).length-1
```

---

## ES5 (39 bytes):

Both functions can be easily adapted to ES5:

```
function B(n){return n?(1&n)+B(n>>1):0}

//ungolfed:

function B(number)
{
    if( number > 0 )
    {
        //arguments.callee points to the function itself
        return (number & 1) + arguments.callee( number >> 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Old one:

```
function(n){return n.toString(2).split(1).length-1}
```

---

[@user1455003](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8055/user1455003) gave me a really great idea, that 'triggered' the smallest one:

```
function B(n,x){for(x=0;n;n>>=1)x+=n&1;return x}
```

I've adapted it to ES6 and made it recursive to shorten a lot!

Comment: Here's a smaller 'reguar' javascript function. function B(n,x){for(x=0;n;n>>=1)x+=n&1;return x}

Comment: @user1455003 Thank you A LOT or your suggestion! I've used it and adapted it to ES6 and shortened a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome!  I like what you did with it. With the recursion regular javascript is down to 39! function B(n){return n?(1&n)+B(n>>1):0}

Comment: @user1455003 If you want, you can edit the ES5 part and add the byte count to the golfed version. (I think you win reputation with edits).

Comment: @user81655 WOW! It works!!! Thank you a lot! I really knew this could be made shorter

Comment: `(1&n)` => `n%2`?

Answer (score 3):

## Forth, <s>48</s> 49 bytes

```
: c ?dup if dup 1- and recurse 1+ then ;
0 1337 c
```

If an actual function is needed then the second line becomes

```
: c 0 swap c ;
```

and you call it by "1337 c". Forth's relatively verbose control words make this a tough one (actually, they make a lot of these tough).

Edit: My previous version did not handle negative numbers correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 18 bytes

`n.to_s(2).count'1'`

Comment: ``n.to_s(2).count ?1`` also works, but is the same length

Comment: 2019 version: n.digits(2).sum / 15 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>72</s> 26 bytes

<sub>Thanks to [mathcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96037/mathcat) for <s>-12</s> <s>-27</s> -36 bytes through various simplifications!</sub>

```python
lambda a:bin(a).count('1')
```

Well, you said *statements*...

Comment: Hi, this can be reduced to [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8I2KTNPIzOvBIgLSks0NDU1rfNsDbjS8osUMhUy8xQqrLg4M9MUMm1t1Q3VrfK0bQ25CopA6vM0//83BgA) by using tabs than spaces and short if.

Comment: Actually, [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EIykzTwNEZ@YVlJZoaGpq6iXnlwL56obqmpr//xsDAA) by using `count`.

Comment: Sorry for these comments, but [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYRvzPycxNyklUSHRKikzTyNRUy85vzSvREPdUF3zf0FRJpBZoQEiM/MKSks0NIHgvzEA) as it is [allowed to use a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) (unless specified in the challenge)

Comment: @mathcat I still have a lot to learn...

Comment: Maybe you can look through [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) post, there are a lot of tips to golf python code there :)

Comment: btw you can use lambdas on any challenge if the OP didn't ask for a "full program"

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 24 bytes + 2 = 26

```
0$11.>~n;
2,:?!^:2%:{+}-
```

The program just does repeated mod 2, subtract and divide until the input number becomes zero, then prints the sum of the mod 2s.

Test with the `-v` flag, e.g.

```
py -3 fish.py ones.fish -v 1337
```

Comment: For a 16bit integer the codepoint input probably not adequate. (The `-v` flag version still works.)

Comment: @randomra Damn, you're right. While Unicode input does work, 16-bit is just a few orders of magnitude out of range...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (38 bytes):

This uses the same aproach as my [ES6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47896/14732)

```
<?=count(split(1,decbin($_GET[n])))-1;
```

This is a full code, you only need to put it in a file and access it over the browser, with the parameter `n=<number>`.

## PHP <4.2 (32 bytes):

This is a little shorter:

```
<?=count(split(1,decbin($n)))-1;
```

This only works reliably on PHP<4.2 because the directive [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) was set to `Off` by default from PHP4.2 up to PHP5.4 (which was removed by then).

If you create a `php.ini` file with `register_globals=On`, this will work.

To use the code, access the file using a browser, with either POST or GET.

## [@ViniciusMonteiro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12700/vinicius-monteiro)'s suggestion (38/45 bytes):

He gave 2 really good suggestions that have a very interesting use of the function `array_sum`:

38 bytes:

```
<?=array_sum(str_split(decbin(1337)));
```

45 bytes:

```
<?=array_sum(preg_split('//', decbin(1337)));
```

This is a really great idea and can be shortened a bit more, to be 36 bytes long:

```
<?=array_sum(split(1,decbin(1337)));
```

Comment: Or you can use echo array_sum(str_split(decbin(1337))); and you can use too echo array_sum(preg_split('//', decbin(1337)));

Comment: @ViniciusMonteiro Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I really loved it! I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Gain four bytes using `<?=substr_count(decbin(1337),"1");` (34 bytes)

Comment: @Cogicero And you can save even more by removing the quotes: `<?=substr_count(decbin(1337),1);`. That is a total of 32 bytes. Considering that it is a different-enough code, don't you want to post it as your own answer? I surelly will upvote it!

Comment: @Cogicero It´s only two bytes shorter if you use parametrization: `<?=substr_count(decbin($argv[1]),1);` (or `$_GET[n]`; 36 bytes)

Comment: You could save 3 bytes with `$argn` and `-F`.

Comment: @Titus While that's true, it isn't worth it. This is a burried answer from 2015. Over 2 years ago. Nobody will care about that saving.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 45 bytes

```
Convert.ToString((ushort)15,2).Sum(b=>b-48);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJDgOY

Comment: `b-48` is even shorter, AFAIK

Comment: Correct! :) I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 3 bytes (non-competitive)

```
¢¬x
```

[Try it here.](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=oqx4&input=MTMzNw==)

Comment: Man, I never see those dates for some reason.

Comment: Haha, Japt is shortest :D BTW, `¢o1 l` would work as well. Another interesting approach is `-¢¬r-0`; `¢¬` splits into array of binary digits, `r-0` reduces by subtraction, starting at 0, and `-` negates the result, making it positive.

Comment: As of last night, you can now use `¢¬x`.

Answer (score 2):

## [beeswax](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Beeswax), <del>31</del> 27 bytes

Non-competing answer. Beeswax is newer than this challenge.

This solution uses Brian Kherigan’s way of counting set bits from the “Bit Twiddling Hacks” website.

it just runs through a loop, incrementing the bit count, while iterating through `number=number&(number-1)` until `number = 0`.
The solution only goes through the loop as often as there are bits set.

I could shave off 4 bytes by rearranging a few instructions. Both source code and explanation got updated:

```
pT_
>"p~0+M~p
d~0~@P@&<
{@<
```

Explanation:

```
pT_            generate IP, input Integer, redirect
>"             if top lstack value > 0 jump next instruction,
               otherwise continue at next instruction
  p            redirect if top lstack value=0 (see below)
   ~           flip top and 2nd lstack values
    0+         set top lstack value to 0, set top=top+2nd
      M        decrement top lstack value
       ~       flip top and 2nd lstack values
        p      redirect to lower left
        <      redirect to left
       &       top=top&2nd
      @        flip top and 3rd lstack values
    @P         increment top lstack value, flip top and 3rd values
 ~0~           flip top and 2nd values, set top=0, flip top and 2nd again
d              redirect to upper left
>"p~0+M.....   loop back

  p            if top lstack = 0 at " instruction (see above), redirect
  0            set lstack top to zero (irrelevant instruction)
  <            redirect to the left
 @             flip top and 3rd lstack values
{              output top lstack value as integer (bitcount)
```

Clone [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl) containing the beeswax interpreter, language spec and examples.

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 3 bytes

```
bSO
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=YlNP&input=MTMzNw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 9 bytes

```
bit-count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZeUWVKeWZyqUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYM3FZWhsbP4fKKebnF@aV/Jf7z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) 3.10+, 13 bytes

```
int.bit_count
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZrM_NK9JIyS-KT80vzSiBi6wqKgKIaaRqGxsbmmpoQwQULIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
{+/2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6rW1jeKqajl4kpTMDQ2NlfQV9C1UzADAE6DBZE=)

*Thanks @coltim for -3 bytes by suggesting me that I can just take the sum instead of the count of `1`s*

Cast the integer into base 2, then sum.

Comment: Rather than removing the `0`s and taking the count, could you just take the sum instead? It would then be straightforward to make it tacit.

Answer (score 2):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 5 bytes

```
?+
 !
```

[Online Interpreter](https://dloscutoff.github.io/Esolangs/BitCycle/?p=c2esc6rc3iAsrqAnrBnrnc2wcw&i=MDAxMQ__)

Kind of  cheaty, as it inputs in binary and outputs in unary. These are the only two I/O formats this language really can handle, but it's also pretty trivial.

---

Explanation:

`?` Take input

`+` Send all 0 bits up (deleting them) and all 1 bits down.

`!` Output all bits that arrive here.

Comment: Isn't this 5? I think you forgot the newline

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 17 bytes

Works for `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int`. Use as a lambda.

```java
Integer::bitCount
```

[Test here](http://ideone.com/i2lxn0)

Without using built-ins:

**42 bytes**

```java
s->{int c=0;for(;s!=0;c++)s&=s-1;return c}
```

[Test here](http://ideone.com/Jggf9B)

Comment: this is a standard loophole: builtin functions that do exactly what you want are forbidden.

Comment: @FUZxxl The OP never forbade standard loopholes

Comment: @ColeJohnson [Standard loopholes are assumed to be closed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/29611)

Comment: @FUZxxl While es1024 is right that the standard loopholes are closed by default, using built-in functions is currently not an accepted loophole at a vote breakdown of +43/-26.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), 6

2 ways:

```
cb2nx1
```

This is a straightforward translation of the requirement: the count of ones in the base-2 representation of number.

```
r+`b2n
```

Another method, which takes the sum of the digits of the base-2 representation.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 18

```
sum(dec2bin(s)-48)
```

Example:

```
octave:1> s=1337
s =  1337
octave:2> sum(dec2bin(s)-48)
ans =  6
```

Answer (score 1):

## GML (Game Maker Language), 21 bytes

```
for(n=0;x;n/=2)n+=x&1
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# 38 bytes

```
Convert.ToString(X,2).Count(C=>C==49);
```

Comment: @Vincent McNabb has suggested a golf which saves one byte (replacing `'1'` with `49`)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 42 bytes

```
#(count(filter #{\1}(Long/toString % 2)))
```

Reading right to left, convert to a binary string, convert to a sequence of characters, filter on `1`s and count how many you have.

**EDITED**
With help from Sieg

Comment: 42: `#(count(filter #{\1}(Integer/toString% 2)))`

Comment: You need one more character `#(count(filter #{\1}(Integer/toString % 2)))`

Comment: No you don't. :)

Comment: This is what I got when I tried it: `CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: toString_PERCENT_`

Comment: I tested it in Try Clojure. Apparently the page suddenly doesn't recognize `Integer/toString`. It worked a second ago though.

Comment: Try Clojure works now.  However your sample fails with the Clojure 1.6.0 REPL.

Comment: Add the space then.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 21

```
$r=grep$v&1<<$_,0..15
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell (51 bytes)

```
"$([char[]][convert]::ToString($s,2)|%{"+$_"})"|iex
```

---

Explanation:
`[convert]::ToString($s,2)` produces a binary string representation from `$s`.
`[char[]]` casts it as a char array and allows us to enumerate each char.
`|%{"+$_"}` prepends each character with a + sign
`"$()"` implicitly calls `.ToString()` on the resulting sub expression
`|iex` sums the piped string (ie. "+1 +0 +1 +1 +0 +1 +0 +0" = 4)

Comment: Hiya! Following the same logic you have, why not use the inline `-join` operator and an implicit `.ToString()` to achieve 45 bytes with `[char[]][convert]::ToString($s,2)-join'+'|iex` ... OR, as a different approach use inline `-replace` operator to achieve 43 bytes with `([convert]::ToString($s,2)-replace0).length`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 42 chars

```
t 0=[]
t n=t(quot n 2)++[rem n 2]
f=sum.t
```

declares the function `f :: Integer -> Integer`
use from the interactive interpreter as `f <number>` or add the line `main=print$f <number>` to the end of the file.

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by directly summing the `rem n 2`s instead of building a list of it and by using `div` instead of `quot`: `t 0=0` `t n=t(div n 2)+rem n 2` - no `f` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 13 bytes

`de2bi` creates a vector of zeros and ones representing the binary number, and `sum` just returns the sum of all the entries.

```
sum(de2bi(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 4 chars / 11 bytes (non-competitive)

```
⨭⟦ïⓑ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=1337&code=%E2%A8%AD%E2%9F%A6%C3%AF%E2%93%91)</kbd>

## Explanation

Converts input to binary, splits along chars, and gets sum of resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

Hooray for built-ins.

```
Ħ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yLL//40NAQ)

Non-built-in:

## Pyt, 3 bytes

```
ɓƖŚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5ORj047O@v/f2BAA)

Explanation:

```
      Implicit input
ɓ     Convert to binary string
Ɩ     Cast as integer
Ś     Sum of digits
      Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ḃ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG8v8PdzRr//9vaGxsDgA)

Just about exactly the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 bytes

```
0$:2%:{+}-2,:@?!n!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30DFykjVqlq7VtdIx8rBXjFP8f///7plCobGxuYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
âΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wonOL//835DLiMuYy4TLlMjM1NYaQZlyGxsbm/3VTAA)

### Explanation

```
â    convert to binary
 Σ   sum(list), digit sum(int)
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to this answer of yours, but I'm unable to find the MathGolf chat anymore.. Is there an infinite loop or infinite list in MathGolf?

Comment: I've been stressed out with school and work for the past few months, so the chat must be inactive. There's no implicit infinite loop, but if you can make sure that the top of the stack evaluates to true you could use the do-while-without-pop. Once I feel that I have time to answer questions on a regular basis, I'll ask to have the chat reopened. Right now I'm just building a todo-list of features I want to add.

Comment: I'm getting "Not yet implemented" ValueErrors for all while / do-while loops.. :S Unless I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: you should use them like `{1}∟` or using the fixed size blocks. It's on my todo-list to have the loop operators also close the block, but it's not implemented as of now.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen just as a side note, you're very welcome to ask questions related to MathGolf like this, I'll answer when I find the time. My goal is to set aside more time for the MathGolf chat, but right now it'll remain closed.

Comment: In that case a few questions. :) Is only `1` truthy in MathGolf (like in 05AB1E), or is `0`/`""`/`[]` falsey and (almost) everything else truthy (like in Python)? And let's say I want an infinite loop printing numbers `1,2,3,...` every time on a new line. I would expect something like `Ä1∟îp` would work, but apparently [it does not](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9wi@GjjvmH1xX8/w8A). What should it be instead?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Maybe I need to clarify the loop structure a bit better, but the correct implementation would be something like [`{îo}▲`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68Lr82kfTNv3/DwA). Your script first does `Ä1∟` which will push 1 onto the stack until the memory is full or TIO timeouts, then it would print the length of the loop. Basically, in pseudo code it would be `int i = 0; do {i++; stack.push(1);} while (i != 0); print(i)`. The code would never reach the last part since the loop is infinite. Basically, loops are constructed as `{<loop code>}<loop operator>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90667/discussion-between-kevin-cruijssen-and-maxb).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 4 bytes

```
+/2\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/19b3yjG0NjY/P9/AA)

Convert to base 2, sum up.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&n%2+f(n>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BboMwEETv/oo9tLGtEoQNgcQIeupXNJVAxLRU1EZgqkpRvp3aJlS9jGZ334z2s/6up2bsBrNX@iKXpS1UUardTj3yp5aosmR0yRGqUCQgQkwAQ9xJLICjxLmDc6mTTECMjm53ciOLvDK3Zdz72PvEq80liKUOZ5m/Hr2e3JX7LPdZzr3GjufJ2hPbRIqq0IzdF6HhNPSdIfisMA1bPb7UzQcxcjJQlHBFAI1Wdnjt1DCbAOTPIBvzBgU4ZgsLwDT/Y/VsLGuRlvjUv9NQT5M9bERx79sA3cuw1@/EY8@AzzPPogMGsdqkwQHcH8H70g5rUQBbwKEVWUvlBR6uq73Ryj5xo/nyCw)

Nice and simple

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
f(x)=floor(mod(x/2^{[0...x]},2)).total
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l6pludbz7z)

*-2 bytes thanks to emanresu A*

Comment: Not sure how to golf this but something like https://www.desmos.com/calculator/chncunsuhu might be shorter?

Comment: @emanresuA thanks that's one byte less and two bytes less with dot notation for `total`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

```sh
a=${$(([##2]$1))//0};<<<$#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9FWpVpFQyNaWdkoVsVQU1Nf36DW2sbGRkU58X8tV5qCCRAbGhubgygzY3PT/wA)
 <sub><s>[30b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P9FWpVpFQyNaWdkoVsVQU1Nf36DW2sbGRkU58X8tV5qCCRAbGhubgygzY3PT/wA)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[35b](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRqVaWaVaw1cTSBRbWWmqaGhEKysbxaoYamrWKhvW1v6v5UpTMAFiQ2NjcxBlZmxu@h8A)</s></sub>

- `$(([##2]$1))` convert input `$1` to binary
- `${ ... //0}` remove `0`s
- `<<<$#a` print length of string `$a`

Answer (score 0):

## K5, 9 bytes

```
+/(16#2)\
```

I used k5's "unpack" overload for `\` to split the number into base 2 digits. You can try it online [here](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20%2B%2F(16%232)%5C1337) using oK.

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 24

This is an adaptation of the C solution by @steveverrill

```
n:=0;for;x>0;n++{x&=x-1}
```

We need to explicitly declare `n` outside the loop to keep it in scope.

Go requires curly braces as well, and the check in the `for` loop must be a boolean expression.

http://play.golang.org/p/Z_iuGL5nZ5

Answer (score 0):

## WDC 65816, 8 bytes

Assuming 8-bit XY (`P.x = 1`), the following 8 bytes of object code produce the popcnt of A in X within 145 cycles:

```
A2 00 4A 90 01 E8 D0 FA
```

This works on a 65816 whether A is 8-bit (`P.m = 1`) or 16-bit (`P.m = 0`), and it has also been tested in a [virtual 6502](http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/index.html) with 8-bit values. With 16-bit XY on a 65816 (`P.x = 0`), one more byte is needed: replace `A2 00` with `A2 00 00`.

Assembly source:

```
  ldx #0       ; A2 00, or A2 00 00 in 16-bit XY mode
loop:
  lsr a        ; 4A    Copy bit 0 of A to carry and shift A right by 1
  bcc zerobit  ; 90 01 If carry is 1, add 1 to X
  inx          ; E8
zerobit:
  bne loop     ; D0 FA If the last ALU result was nonzero, keep counting
```

The `bne` instruction branches on the zero flag, which changes whenever an instruction writes to register A, X, or Y. For a 1 bit, `inx` is the last instruction to write to A, X, or Y, and X is nonzero if there are 1 to 255 bits (only 16 are possible!), so the loop continues. For a 0 bit, `lsr a` is the last instruction to write to A, X, or Y, and A is nonzero only if there are more bits to count.

Answer (score 0):

perl (35 characters)

```
$b=sprintf("%b",$d);$c=()=$b=~/1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), 22 chars (25 for full program, or 27 for working with zero)

```
[Fy?!%lyWOO])Fmy#WilyW
```

Prefix this with `F<some value>` to get the answer for that value. Or, for a full program to read from stdin, prefix the code with `Fnx`. In a [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/check-whether-an-integer-is-a-power-of-2-without-using-operations/47761#47761), I golfed a way in Clip to check if something's a power of two. I always return one in that case. Otherwise, increment the result of applying this function (recursively) to `2^(floor(log2(<function parameter>)))`.

To make this work with zero (returning 0), use (28 chars):

```
[Fy?!yZ]?!%lyWOO])Fmy#WilyW
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <strike>63</strike> <strike>51</strike> 47 bytes

```
[ $1 = 0 ]&&echo 0||echo $[$1%2+`$0 $[$1/2]`]
```

The shorter the code, the clearer the meaning :).

---

#### 51:

```
[ $1 -ne 0 ]&&echo $[($1&1)+$($0 $[$1/2])]||echo 0
```

Recursive script instead of script with recursing function.

---

The "`negative-cond || instruction`" idiom instead of boring
"`if cond; then instruction; fi` " is our friend here.

Note that echo should return 0 (true), so `[ $1 -ne 0 ] && echo $[$[$1&1]+$(n $[$1/2])]`

has the logical value of `[ $1 -ne 0 ]` alone.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6: 17

The first thing that comes to mind is

```perl6
[+] 1337.base(2).comb; # returns 6
```

---

Although this doesn't have any arbitrary limits ( the only limits are how much memory you have, and how long you are willing to wait )

```perl6
[+] ( uint64.Range.max * 2 + 1 ).base(2).comb; # returns 65

# 340282366920938463463374607431768211455
my $uint128-max = :2( 1 x 128 );
[+] $uint128-max.base(2).comb; # returns 128

my $uint8192-max = :2( 1 x 8192 ); # 2467 digit Int
[+] $uint8192-max.base(2).comb; # returns 8192 (takes about a second currently)
```

Without making it into a [Callable](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Callable) the shortest way to write this is to put the Int into the *"default"* variable `$_`. ( `.method` is always short for `$_.method` )

```perl6
$_ = 1337;
[+] .base(2).comb;
```

```perl6
given 1337 { # Perl6's with/switch statement
  [+] .base(2).comb
}
```

```perl6
[+] .base(2).comb given 1337; # ditto
```

```perl6
if 1337 -> $_ { # pointy block
  [+] .base(2).comb
}
```

If you want to create a [Callable](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Callable) you could just put it into a [Block](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Block).

```perl6
my $code-ref = {[+] .base(2).comb};
# if it is called with an argument it places it in $_
# if called without an argument uses the $_ from an outer scope
```

If you really want to call it as a normal subroutine:

```perl6
my &f={[+] .base(2).comb}; # sub f($_){[+] .base(2).comb}

say f 1337; # 6

$_ = 1337;
say f; # 6
```

---

Based on your requirements I'd guess that the answer you are looking for is:

```perl6
[+] .base(2).comb
```

This assumes that the value is already in `$_`. It would most likely be the last statement in a subroutine, the right side of an assignment, or an argument to a subroutine or method. ( Otherwise it calculates the result only to throw it away, unless the compiler notices that the result is unused )

---

In case you were wondering `[+] 1, 2, 3` can be considered short for `(1,2,3).reduce(&[+])`.
Where `&[+]` is short for `&infix:< + >` the collection of multi subs available in the current scope that are responsible for the numerical infix addition operator `+`.

Answer (score 0):

### ActionScript 3, 17 bytes

```
for(;x;n++)x&=x-1
```

This is a copy of [steveverrill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47875/10588) answer, how ever by using AS3, I don't have to put `;` at the end of the line, so I save 1 byte.

Also I assume that `x` and `n` been initialize already.

Answer (score 0):

## [O](http://o.readthedocs.org/), 7 bytes

```
H2b~]+o
```

Explanation:

```
H        Push input into array
  2b~    Push all the bits of the binary form to the array
     ]+o Add them all up and output the array
```

Answer (score 0):

## TeaScript, 9 bytes (non-competitive)

```
x÷f»l¦1)n
```

[Try it here.](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22x%C3%B7f%C2%BBl%C2%A61)n%22&inputs=%5B%221337%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:true,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

Answer (score 0):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes (non-competitive)

This one is fun and neat, and given the number of non-competitive entries it has attracted, I might as well add a Seriously answer.

```
'12,¡c
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2731322cad63&input=1337)

Explanation:

```
'12,¡c
   ,     get input
  2 ¡    convert to binary string
'1   c   count the occurrences of "1"
         (implicit print at EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 15 bytes

I would have thought this would do a bit better, but the lack of an operator to convert numbers to a base 2 string seems to have hurt it.  Maybe in a future version of Candy to pull an int from the stack and push 1's and 0's.  That would make this one kind of boring, just `XS?`.

```
(~A2%h2/LD{)|=Z
```

The long form is:

```
while   # stack not empty
  peekA
  pushA    
  digit2
  mod       # get low bit
  popAddZ   # Z = Z + low bit
  digit2
  div
  floor     # integer div 2
  dupl
  if        # if the top of stack is non-zero
endwhile    # NOTE that the endwhile is in an if-then clause
  else
    popA
    pushZ   # NOTE the lack of an endif.
            #  braces and parens are calculated as the
            #  program counter advances over them
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# 45**

```
int o=Convert.ToString(n,2).Count(x=>x=='1');
```

where **o** holds the amount of ones and where **n** is the number.

Alternative and faster
**C# 6.0 88 bytes**

```
int o=b(n,16).Count(x=>x=='1');
static string b(int v,int l)=>(l>1?b(v>>1,l-1):null)+"01"[v&1];
```

where the **o** holds the number of ones and where the **n** is the number.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 35 bytes

```
a=>a.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
```

Answer (score 0):

**x86 cpu instructions, 30 bytes**

```
56 89 E6 8B 44 04 3D 00 00 74 0F D1 E8 50 E8 EF FF 8B 4C 04 81 E1 01 00 01 C8 5E C2 02 00
```

meaning and disassembly:

```
; input in the stack sp+4
; output in ax
;0i,2Ka,4P
f:  
push  si
mov   si,  sp
mov   ax,  [si+4]
cmp   ax,  0
je   .z
shr   ax,  1
push  ax
call  f
mov   cx,  [si+4]
and   cx,  1
add   ax,  cx
.z:  
pop   si
ret 2


0000000F  56                push si
00000010  89E6              mov si,sp
00000012  8B4404            mov ax,[si+0x4]
00000015  3D0000            cmp ax,0x0
00000018  740F              jz 0x29
0000001A  D1E8              shr ax,1
0000001C  50                push ax
0000001D  E8EFFF            call 0xf
00000020  8B4C04            mov cx,[si+0x4]
00000023  81E10100          and cx,0x1
00000027  01C8              add ax,cx
00000029  5E                pop si
0000002A  C20200            ret 0x2
//30
```

Answer (score 0):

## RProgN, 8 Bytes

```
2 B S ++
```

## Explination

```
2 B     # Convert to base 2
S       # Convert from string to a stack of individual characters
++      # Sum the stack.
```

Simple enough, Could be made cheaper if the sugar for sum was single character, instead of double, as `►2BS<SUM>` could then be used, saving a byte.

## Test Cases

```
1337:       6.0
16:         1.0
255:        8.0
1236172031: 21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

### 16/32-bit x86 assembly, 9 bytes

(based on es1024's answer)

```
31 C0 D1 E9 10 E0 41 E2 F9
```

which is equivalent to:

```
xor ax, ax        ; 31 C0   Set ax to 0
shr cx, 1         ; D1 E9   Shift cx to the right by 1 (cx >> 1)
adc al, ah        ; 10 E0   al += (ah = 0) + (cf = rightmost bit before shifting)
inc cx            ; 41      Increment cx to offset following decrement
loop $-5          ; 75 F9   Jump up to shr cx, 1 if cx-1 is not zero
```

cx is the 16-bit integer to profile, result is returned in ax.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

(The language postdates the question, barely.)

```
1NTBa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/f0C/EKfE/kDY2NgcA)

With the knowledge that `a` represents the first command-line argument, this program can be understood quite straightforwardly: `1 iN To-Binary(a)`. That is, convert `a` to binary and count the number of `1`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
:B|+
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AB%7C%2B&i=1337&a=1)

### Explanation

```
:B|+
:B      Binary digits
  |+    Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì2
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=7DI&input=MTMzNw)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 25 bytes

```
[2~rd0<B]dsBx[+z1<S]dsSxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2hsbP4/2qiuKMXAxik2pdipIlq7ytAmGMgMrij4/x8A)

Two macros.
`[2~rd0<B]dsBx` breaks a decimal value down into binary components by repeatedly dividing by two (using `~` to leave both quotient and remainder on stack) until left with a quotient of zero. After our stack is filled with ones and zeros, `[+z1<S]dsSx` sums it up by adding the top two values until there's only one value left. `p` prints our final answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L,BBBDBs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8nJycWp@P///4bGxuYA)

Surprisingly short for Add++

### How it works

```
L,      ; Define a lambda function
        ; Example argument: 1337
    BB  ; Binary;  STACK = [10100111001]
    BD  ; Digits;  STACK = [[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1]]
    Bs  ; Sum;     STACK = [6]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

```
{it.toString(2).sumBy{it-'0'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQn5dabKWg4ZlXoqmga6cApBVs/1dnluiV5AeXFGXmpWsYaeoVl@Y6VQIFddUN1Gtr/6eV5inkJmbmaWgqVHMpAAHIoMy8glKgXoWi1MQUn8y8VA1NsBQI2AMNAxqMLGKlYADmFACtKNEAOUIDbICmJlftf0NLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 6 bytes

```
uJ$);1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v9RLRdPa8P9/Q2NjcwA)

### Explanation

```
:uJ$);1
:            implicit :
              mode: sequence 1 - given input n, output nth term in sequence
             each term in the sequence is

 u   ;1      count(                , 1)
  J )              toBase(     , 2)
   $                      index
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 13 bytes

```
hammingweight
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWazMSc3Mz89LLUzPTM0ogYusKijLzSjTSNAyNjc01NSGCCxZAaAA)

PARI/GP has a built-in for this.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 17 bytes

```
n->sumdigits(n,2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWG_N07YpLc1My0zNLijXydIw0IeLrCooy80o00jQMjY3NNaGCCxZAaAA)

Another built-in, with a more obvious name.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 21 bytes

```
f(n)=if(n,n%2+f(n\2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWW9M08jRtM4GkTp6qkTaQjjHS1ITIrSsoyswr0UjTMDQ2NocJwjQCAA)

Without built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

```perl6
*.base(2).comb.sum
```

Works with any nonnegative integer, in fact.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@19LLymxOFXDSFMvOT83Sa@4NPe/NVdafpGCjZmBgqW5gqGBgYKhsbG5nUI1F2dxYqWCkkq8gi6Ql6agEl@rxFX7HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## 8051 Machine Code, 13 bytes

```
7B 10 E8 13 50 01 0A BB 08 01 E9 DB F6
```

Takes the integer in R1 (highest 8 bits) and R0 (lowest 8 bits). Returns the result in R2

```
    MOV R3, #10        ; 7B 10     - Store 16 since we process a 16 bit number
    MOV A, R0          ; E8        - Move the first register to check to A

LAB1:
    RRC A              ; 13        - Rotate A through the carry to extract the nth bit
    JNC LAB2           ; 50 01     - If the current bit is set (Carry = 1)
    INC R2             ; 0A        - Increment the result

LAB2:
    CJNE R3, #08, LAB3 ; BB 08 01  - If we are done with the first 8 bits
    MOV A, R1          ; E9        - Move R1 into the accumulator

LAB3:
    DJNZ R3, LAB1      ; DB F6     - Jump back to LOOP if we have done less than 16 iterations
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SMALL](http://csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/small.html), 28 bytes

```
0->n{x?[x%2=1?n+1->n]x/2->x}
```

Takes input in variable `x` and the output will be in variable `n`.

```
{
  x?
  
  [
    x % 2 = 1?
    n + 1 -> n
  ]
  
  x / 2 -> x
}
```

Repeatedly divides `x` by two until the number is zero, which means every 1 bit will be moved into its rightmost bit at some point. We then perform a check each loop to see if this bit is a 1 and if so, increment `n`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2B
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhaLjJyWFCclF0O5C5YYGhubQ9gA)

Convert to a binary list. `S` flag takes the sum.

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃ1c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSx_uaDZMXlKclFwMFVmwxNDY2BzCBgA)

Convert to binary and count the 1s.

Answer (score -1):

### LUA 55 bytes

```
while(i>0)do if(v-i)>=0 then c=c+1;v=v-i;end i=i/2 end
```

> **v**    is the value
>
> **i**    is the max value of an (x)bit Integer, 65535 in this example.
>
> **c**    counts one up, if there's a remainder from (i-l), which means that a one is found.

This is more a simple algorithm than a single statement.

Comment: Not valid, c is not declared, and will error when (c=c+1) happens, you cannot assume i is a value, and you cannot assume the input is v.
Please use the standard io methods.

Comment: Uhm,.. what? You can declare by defining in lua.

Comment: The declaring of these things must be part of the code.

Comment: EG,
`i=65535 c=0 v = io.read() while(i>0)do if(v-i)>=0 then c=c+1;v=v-i;end i=i/2 end`